# How to change PHP-User/Group from Root|Root to Nobody|Nogroup?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, virtualbox

We have a Local-Server that runs Ubuntu 15 LTS (Virtual-Host-System).
We use VirtualBox as VM-Software. 
We have many Virtualservers in Virtualbox (Virtual-Guest-System). 
All of this VM-Servers are Ubuntu-Server 16 LTS (with PHP (5.3,5.6,7), Apache, and so on).

For the different Php-Versions we use: 
https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/
Each Server has only one Php-Version running.

Php executed by apache mod = `a2enmod php5.6`

On the Virtual-Host-System we have ONE shared Folder (`/media/daten/server`) with all Web-Server-Folders (for the different VM-Guest-Servers).
Each VM-Guest-Server has this folder including as (`/media/sf_server`) -> with VM-Guest-Additions

Our Employments using Windows (7 and 10). All Employments including the Serverfolder as Networkfolder. If an Employment copies and pastes files to the Server-Directory all the files get automatic `USER: nobody | Group: nogroup`.

This is the Reason why we config Apache as `USER: nobody | Group: nogroup`. (`/etc/apache2/envvars`). Thats works fine. Apache can run/write/delete all files without any Problems.

But when we use a phpscript for upload/upgrade (upload, wordpress, typo3) then these uploaded-files get `User: Root | Group: User`

`echo exec('whoami');` = `nobody` | 
`echo get_current_user();` = `root`

---

Ftp is not running on the VM's.

All Scripts started from Webbrowser/Php/Apache2.

Example 1:
Default Wordpress Updatescript can't create a wp-config-sample.php
(updates without ftp - FS_METHOD: direct)

Example 2:
Typo3 upload an image:
Uploaded file could not be moved! Write-permission problem in "fileadmin/img/"?

---

- **How can we run all PHP-Tasks (Upload, etc) as `USER: nobody | Group: nogroup`???**
- **Or what is the best/secure way to make this solution working??**

---

thanks a lot

Comment: How is php executed? Via apache mod or fastcgi (fpm)?

Comment: apache mod = `a2enmod php5.6`

Comment: *phpscript for upload/upgrade* what did you use? fileputcontents or simualar funtions or did you use ftp functions? who start the scrips? apache or did you execute it via system etc?

Comment: Ftp is not running on the VM's.

All Scripts started from Webbrowser/Php/Apache2.

Example 1:
Default Wordpress Updatescript can't create a wp-config-sample.php
(updates without ftp - FS_METHOD: direct)

Example 2:
Typo3 upload an image:
Uploaded file could not be moved! Write-permission problem in "fileadmin/img/"?

Answer (score 0):

When using TYPO3, you can configure which group should be set for created or uploaded files. You have to set the following configuration variable.

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['createGroup'] = 'nogroup';
```

However, this only works for uploads that are actually handled by the TYPO3 api. Have a look at

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::upload_copy_move()
```

to get an impression on how TYPO3 handles file uploads.